# MinRole Topologies

Tags: topology, distributedcache, 2016, minrole

What are MinRole topologies and what is the best practice to configure topologies in SharePoint 2016? What are the differences between front end servers and Distributed Cache servers?

Answer (score 1):

Without using the Custom MinRole, MinRole High Availability will require a minimum of 9 servers; 3 Distributed Cache, 2 Web Front Ends, 2 Search, and 2 Application Servers. Licensing and hardware availability will determine what topology you will pick; this will determine the route for 'best practice'. I suspect many companies will continue to use a Custom role, provisioning services manually.

Distributed Cache servers run DC, while FEs run a variety of services, including the Foundation Web service (DCs also run this, but you shouldn't use them as FEs using the dedicated MinRole).

[MinRole Overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346114%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)